# Failed to load resource; the server responded with a status of 404 - bundles/jquery - MVC

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using bundling in MVC ASP.net

**Here is my BundleConfig class.**
 public class BundleConfig
    {

```
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.IgnoreList.Clear();

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundle/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundle/js").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundle/css").Include(
                    "~/Content/bootstrap.min.css",
                    "~/Content/bootstrap.css"));

    }
}
```

**_Layout.cshtml** Here I am rendering bundles

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/bundle/css")
</head>
<body>
    @RenderBody()
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundle/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundle/js")
</body>
</html>
```

On running my application I get error in browser console

**Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)** for all bundles

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you registering bundles (Global.asax):

```
protected virtual void Application_Start() {
   BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
}
```

Comment: @DheerajKumar error in the title suggested it was looking for bundles/jquery. Make sure you are registering bundles per my updated answer.

Comment: This is it. Thanks a lot. Since I had created BundleConfig class manually. I didnt think about this part.